# Splitting the data with comma separation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to split the data in a column with comma separation?

I am attaching the images for my Input and my expecting output.

The following is the input:

[enter link description here](http://bytes.com/attachments/attachment/8211d1423644360/input.png)

The following is my expected output:

[enter link description here](http://bytes.com/attachments/attachment/8212d1423644360/output.png)

Please help me how I will get my required output with a SQL Server query

Thanks in advance,
Phani Kumar.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: It is a duplicate but not of that one. That one splts into columns. OP wants to split into rows. This one might suit better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco

Comment: Don't store data like comma separated items is the answer! As you have noticed it will only cause you problems!!!

Comment: writing links in your question it not a good way to present data. Naming <it enter link description here> doesn't make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @t Table (ID INT,Groupname VARCHAR(10),Pid  VARCHAR(20))

insert into @t (ID,Groupname,Pid)values (1,'xxxx','123,568,562,25')
insert into @t (ID,Groupname,Pid)values (2,'yyyy','2,356,321')
insert into @t (ID,Groupname,Pid)values (3,'zzzz','7,898,569')
insert into @t (ID,Groupname,Pid)values (4,'sss','12345')

SELECT ID,Groupname,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'Values' 
FROM  
(
     SELECT ID,Groupname,
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Pid], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM @t     
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mohan for you quick and correct response.